# Frequent, "random" SQL Server connection timeouts

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

For the last few days our clients have been suffering intermittent connection timeouts to our database server.

Multiple Ajax calls on the same page which connect to the server multiple times are having mixes of success and failure, and at times specific website users are getting connection issues while other users are not from the same site.

I am not sure if the issue lies with the databases or the server itself, but we may be having connection issues to a different database on the same server.

The server is an Amazon Cloud VPC running Windows Server 2008 RC, and the version of SQL Server is SQL Server 2008 R2. I can provide more information if necessary.

Can someone give me any hints on how to go about debugging this? Maybe a few methods to test the connections?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, when you failed to connect to your SQL Server, the issue
> could be:
>
> 1. Network issue.
> 2. SQL Server configuration issue.
> 3. Firewall issue.
> 4. Client driver issue.
> 5. Application configuration issue.
> 6. Authentication and logon issue.

I thik you can follow [THIS article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_protocols/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues) for more information.

Comment: The link to the article is now returning a 404 error.